# Unit Testing angularjs custom component with external template and service breaks when the template is external

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, templates, service, external

Hi I have created a custom component that uses an external template and requires a service, when the template is defined as external, the unit tests break. 
template reference in main.html `<cc-accordion items="genres"></cc-accordion>`
This is the component js

```
angular.module("ccAccordion", [])
.directive("ccAccordion", function () {
 return {
      restrict: "AE",
      templateUrl: "components/accordion/accordion.html",
      scope: {
          items: "="
      },
      link: function (scope) {
          scope.$watch("items", function (items) {
              angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                  item.selected = false;
              });

             scope.select = function (index) {
                  (scope.items[index].selected === true ) ? scope.items[index].selected = false : scope.items[index].selected = true;
                  angular.forEach(scope.items, function (item, key) {
                      if(key !== index) {
                        item.selected = false;  
                      }
                  });
              };
          });
      }
  };
 });
```

here is the unit test

```
describe('ccAccordion', function () {
var elm, scope;
beforeEach(module('ccAccordion'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    elm = angular.element(
      '<cc-accordion items="genres"></cc-accordion>'
   );

    scope = $rootScope;
    scope.genres = [{
            title: 'Scifi', 
            description: 'Scifi description'
        }, {
            title: 'Comedy',
            description: 'Comedy description'
        }];
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should create clickable titles', function () {
    var titles = elm.find('.cc-accord h2');

    expect(titles.length).toBe(2);
    expect(titles.eq(0).text().trim()).toBe('Scifi');
    expect(titles.eq(1).text().trim()).toBe('Comedy');
});

it('should bind the content', function () {
    var contents = elm.find('.cc-accord-content p');

    expect(contents.length).toBe(2);
    expect(contents.eq(0).text().trim()).toBe('Scifi description');
    expect(contents.eq(1).text().trim()).toBe('Comedy description');

});

it('should change active content when header clicked', function () {
    var titles = elm.find('.cc-accord h2'),
        divs = elm.find('.cc-accord');

    // click the second header
    titles.eq(1).find('a').click();

    // second div should be active
    expect(divs.eq(0)).not.toHaveClass('active');
    expect(divs.eq(1)).toHaveClass('active');
});
});
```

here is the template

```
<div class="cc-accord" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active:item.selected}" ng-click="select($index)">
 <h2><a>
      {{item.title}} <cc-up-down-arrow></cc-up-down-arrow>
     </a></h2>
   <div class="cc-accord-content"><p>{{item.description}}</p></div>
</div>
```

if I put the template in the directive the tests pass. I've tried editing the karma.conf to use a preprocessor and 'ng-html2js' but can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

here is my karma.conf, I'm using mean stack to scaffold the app

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',
    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'client/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-     router.js',
        'client/app/app.js',
        'client/app/**/*.js',
        'client/components/**/*.js',
        'client/app/**/*.html',
        'client/components/**/*.html'
    ],

    preprocessors: { 
        'client/components/accordion/accordion.html': 'ng-html2js'
    },
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        /*stripPrefix: 'client/',
        stripSufix: '.ext',
        // prepend this to the
        prependPrefix: 'served/'*/
    },
    ngJade2JsPreprocessor: {
        stripPrefix: 'client/'
    },
    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],
    // web server port
    port: 8080,
    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,
    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
});
```

};

New matcher function for jasmine 2.0

```
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveClass: function () {
            return {
                compare: function (actual, expected) {
                    var classTest = actual.hasClass(expected);
                    classTest ? classTest = true : classTest = false;
                    return {
                        pass: classTest,
                        message: 'Expected ' + angular.mock.dump(actual) + ' to have class ' + expected
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Usage

```
expect(divs.eq(0)).not.toHaveClass('active');
expect(divs.eq(1)).toHaveClass('active');
```

Comment: Had the same issue a few days ago and solved it. Can you provide your karma conf and some information about your directory structure?

Comment: Hi Hismmet, thanks for getting back to me, I've added the karma.conf :D

Comment: directory structure is /client/app/main, and /client/components/accordion etc

Comment: The module is referenced in main.html (not the template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just compared you karma config file with mine, seeing following differences:

- In field preprocessors, try providing an array instead of a single processor
- Use  ngHtml2JsPreprocessor field

Your karma conf file should contain following:

```
preprocessors: {
    'client/components/accordion/accordion.html': ['ng-html2js']
},
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    stripPrefix: 'client/'
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Himmet, that worked, I also had to create a new custom matcher function for jasmine 2.0, which I've added to the code if you're interested, I've added it to the question ;D

Answer (score 0):

As Himmet said the karma.conf file needs to be edited and you need to put the location of the template into the preprocessors section

```
preprocessors: {
'client/components/accordion/accordion.html': ['ng-html2js'],
'another-template-path/template.html': ['ng-html2js']
},
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  stripPrefix: 'client/'
}
```